# Brackets and assignment inside of php's IF

Tags: php

Question:

Code 1 and Code 2 has got 1 difference - brackets.

I do not get why 1st causes error but 2nd not.

Code 1:

```
if
(
    $response = $myObject->response($request)
    && $response2 = $myObject->response($response) // PHP Notice: Undefined variable: response 
)
```

Code 2:

```
if
(
    ($response = $myObject->response($request))
    && $response2 = $myObject->response($response) // Everything is OK
)
```

Comment: `==` is for equals not `=`. `=` is an assignment operator.

Comment: Yes, I know that = is assigment and == is equals ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&&` operator has higher [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `=` operator.

The brackets change the order of the evaluation to what you desire, as expressions in brackets are evaluated first(as they do in math).

Answer (score 2):

As @baldrs mentioned, the `&&` operator (logical and) has higher [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than the assignment operator. Adding parenthesis forces the evaluation of the assignment before the evaluation of the logical and.

Comment: What's the point in saying exactly the same I did in my answer before?

Comment: You made no mention of why the parenthesis affects the evaluation in your initial post. you edited it as I was typing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

By giving the bracket ( ) on the whole statement defines the scope, while in the first check they are 2 independent checks with different scopes.

```
if you define $response  above the if check, it will work as well.

( ) <-- They broaden the scope of the if check that is why it is visible in the second check.
```

Answer (score 1):

It because `&&` operator has higher precedence than `=` operator in `PHP`. Also apply sense of `BODMAS` rule as in maths, every operation inside bracket is done first.
See table lists the operators in order of precedence for `PHP`:

[Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 0):

The first one is equal to:

```
if (
    $response = (
        $myObject->response($request) &&
        ($response2 = $myObject->response($response)) // the $response is not defined here
    )
)
```

---

The second one is equal to:

```
if (
    ($response = $myObject->response($request))      // the $response is defined here
    && ($response2 = $myObject->response($response)) // so you can use it  
)
```

Comment: The second one is not like that. It's `if ($response = ($myObject->response($request) && $response2) = $myObject->response($response))` which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

As several others already said, `&&` has higher priority than `=` (which is assignment, not comparison) and your code is the same as `if ($a = ($b && $c) = $d)` (put your own expressions instead of `$a` .. `$d`).

This reads: "assign `$d` to `$b && $c` then assign it to `$a`". But `$b && $c` is an expression, not a variable, you cannot assign `$d` to it. It's like you say "store `$d` in `2+2`".

Check the [operators precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) in PHP manual.

If your intention is to do assignments then write it like `if (($a = $b) && ($c = $d))`, otherwise use the correct comparison operator `if ($a == $b && $c == $d)` and you don't need to use parenthesis.